# Quick way to extract simple strings from Excel xlsx files

Tags: windows, file, excel, xlsx, vba

Where I work I have a few hundred xlsx files (created with Office 2010 Starter) that I need to extract information from. This is a one time job only, so the question is which way is the quickest. Existing tool? Programming a solution?

The information is just strings, formatting does not matter. These files contain customer data. One file for each customer. And before you ask, yes, it's a silly system - and we are abandoning it. Because we are now moving to a new system, we need to export the existing customer data to a CSV file that can be imported in the new system.

If I were to write a computer program to do this, I would need to be able to access the first worksheet in each file, and be able to read the contents of any given cell (A1, C5 etc.). That's it.

Since an xlsx-file is just some zipped XML files, one approach would be to write code that unzips and parses the XML files. That smells like a very time consuming solution so I would rather use a free library if one exists.

Of the languages that could be useful here, I am best at C++ and C, but have done some C#, VB6 and VB.NET, as well as a tiny bit of Python.

Comment: Since you have VB6 experience and this is a one-time need, a quick Excel VBA macro seems the most obvious approach (but of course that may reflect some of my own biases...)

Comment: Øystein, did you get this to work?

Comment: @HeadofCatering Sorry for the delay, I had completely forgotten about this question as the transition to the new system was delayed. Your macro is nice, so I'll use that when the transition happens. Thanks ;)

Comment: No worries -- I was just curious to know if it worked for you. Good luck with the transition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all your Excel files in a single folder if they aren't already and follow these steps:

1. Open a blank workbook
2. Open VBA Editor <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>
3. Add a module:  Insert --> Module
4. Add the code below into the module (change the directory string to point to the directory where your to-be-converted Excel files live)
5. Step through a few files to make sure it's doing what you expect
6. <kbd>F5</kbd> to run on all files
7. Say good-bye to your old system

**code:**

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub ExportAllToCSV()
        Dim Directory As String
        Dim i As Long
        Dim file As String
        Directory = "C:\workbooks\"
        i = 1

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        ' Get the first file
        file = Dir(Directory, vbReadOnly + vbHidden + vbSystem)

        Do While file <> ""
            If Right(file, 4) = "xlsx" Then ' change to right(file ,3) = "xls" if you have xls files instead of xlsx
                Workbooks.Open Filename:=file
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\workbooks\file" & i & ".csv", FileFormat _
                            :=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
                ActiveWorkbook.Close
                i = i + 1
            End If

            ' Get the next file
            file = Dir()
        Loop

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have the macro move the cell of interest to the upper left corner and delete the remainder of the sheet before saving, and this problem becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [Excel interop API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200).  An example of how to use the API is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/6264b659-f366-4c29-817b-d51b738212f5).

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you can use C#, there is a excellent library for Excel 2007+ files, [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). Here are some examples to get you started :

```
  ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("excelfile.xlsx"));
  // take the first sheet 
  // or you could get the Worksheet with name : ep.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"]
  ExcelWorksheet ws = ep.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

  // now you can get data
  // cell data from row 3, column 2 (first row or column is 1 not 0)
  string data = ws.Cells[3, 2].Value.ToString();
  // from A5 cell
  string data1 = ws.Cells["A5"].Value.ToString();

  // you can find out how many rows are there 
  int maxRow = ws.Dimension.End.Row;
```